# Bind data to a Session Variable?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, data-binding, session-variables

I have a CustomerID being retrieved and set into a Global Variable.

What I need is to use that Customer ID on the same page (code behind) and use it as a parameter for a SqlDataSource query.

Then I want to store the results of the query (the customers zipcode) into a session variable. All of this need to happen in the same click event.

How can I Bind data to a Session variable. I don't want to bind it to a control first. I just want the data (zip code) to be stored right into the Session Var.

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: I'm retrieving data from a database. Not Storing a session to a database. I just need to store the data from the DB in my session var to send to the next page. I did not see an example of that on the Session State Overview article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should 
Session["DataName"] = code to get items not work?

Comment: yeah. that's where I'm stuck. the "code to get items" I'm not sure how to write that code. looking for an example.

Comment: you can bind any object to the session so the code that you use to get your dataset object is the code that goes there so Session["DataName"] = new DataSet(); will bind a DataSet to the session.